# How can I block websites for specific PCs on my network?

Tags: windows, home-networking, blocking

I want to see if I can monitor the traffic on my home network, and block specific websites for specific PCs.

Is there a way to do this remotely (i.e.: without physically accessing the PC), and additionally, can it be bypassed with a VPN?

All PCs in question are using Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, with a corporate firewall setup in between the traffic you wish to route, maybe some managed router or switch too potentially as well. Many ways to skin this cat, which is applicable in your particular situation? If you have all these parts in place, doing it remotely is 100% for sure applicable. What you working with over there on your tropical island in paradise? Maybe even with a cool Python script sending floods of UDP packets as well if you wanted to do it in a malicious manner but you may hose up some switches and/or routers when doing it. But it works too.

Comment: You can also consider installing parental control software on the computers in question.  As long as the people using it don't have admin abilities, they can't remove it.
You'd need to physically access the computer once to install it (unless you can do a remote login), but after that, most can be configured via a website.

Comment: @McDonald's simply put, someone in the house has been going on websites they shouldn't be and I want to secretly block them from doing so. Ideally without having to purchase anything - is that possible?

Comment: Yes, per PC and updating the files accordingly see these two posts for a starting point but again this is a ***per PC*** solution, free, and simple too: http://www.guidingtech.com/4868/edit-hosts-file-block-websites/ and https://steemit.com/block/@barryallen/how-to-block-facebook-with-hosts-file-for-windows. You can do this remotely too with `c$` share or executing commands with psexec or something by the way. Otherwise, consider RDP into the machine as administrator and modify from there.

Answer (score 0):

OpenDNS can allow you to monitor the websites and block selected websites. If you need to block a specific device, you might have to buy the VIP version:

https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/220047987-Blocking-on-only-one-computer

However, OpenDNS can be easily bypassed by simply changing the default DNS server, which can be done on virtually any device. VPN's can also bypass OpenDNS, however, a possible solution to to block the VPN server.

Alternately, depending on the router you have, there may be built in parental control features. Type in the IP address of your router's gateway and look around for the features.

Answer (score 0):

- Buy a Raspberry Pi
- Install Pi-Hole
- Use it as your DNS server

Pi-Hole can block advertisements and internet trackers, but it can also block whatever websites you desire via a custom blocklist.

You can even use it as a DHCP server. It can also be used as a network monitoring tool.

It can be bypassed by using a VPN, just like OpenDNS.

The software can be found at https://pi-hole.net/

The documentation can be found at https://docs.pi-hole.net/

It is very easy to set up and configure. It is free and opensource.

If by

> someone in the house has been going on websites they shouldn't be

you mean porn then there is a (huge) blocklist for those websites. But having a healthy discussion may be better.

https://github.com/chadmayfield/my-pihole-blocklists/tree/master/lists